# Python Drivers License Exam

Tags: python

I want this to compare the strings in the list but when I output it it compares the correct list to the same string of the other list 20 times each. I would appreciate if I could get some help to see what i'm doing wrong

```
def main():        

        submitted = ['A','D','C','A','C','A','D','C','A','D','A','C','B','D','A','C','C','A','D','B']

        outfile  = open('submitted.txt', 'w')

        for item in submitted:

            outfile.write(item + '\n')

        outfile.close()

        infile = open('submitted.txt', 'r')

        submitted = infile.readlines()

        infile.close()

        sub_count = 0

        while sub_count < len(submitted):
            submitted[sub_count] = submitted[sub_count].rstrip('\n')
            sub_count += 1

        print 'The answers you submitted were ', submitted
        print '******************************************************************************************'


        correct = ['A','C','A','A','D','B','C','A','C','B','A','D','C','A','D','C','B','B','D','A']

        outfile  = open('correct.txt', 'w')

        for item in correct:

            outfile.write(item + '\n')

        outfile.close()

        infile = open('correct.txt', 'r')

        correct = infile.readlines()

        infile.close()

        cor_count = 0

        while cor_count < len(correct):
            correct[cor_count] = correct[cor_count].rstrip('\n')
            cor_count += 1

        print 'The correct answers are ', correct
        print '******************************************************************************************'

        print 'BELOW IS THE COMPARISON OF YOUR ANSWERS TO THE CORRECT ANSWERS'

        correct_count = 0

        incorrect_count = 0

        number_questions = 0

        while (number_questions < 20):

          number_questions += 1

          for ans in submitted:
              for cor in correct:
                  if cor == ans:
                        print cor, ans ,' = correct'
                        correct_count += 1

                  elif cor != ans:
                      incorrect_count += 1
                      print cor, ans ,' = wrong'


main()
```

Comment: Please narrow down your code to just the part you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating over **all** of the pairs of submitted/correct responses, while you want to be iterating over the **matched** pairs. Instead use:

```
for ans, cor in zip(submitted, correct):
    if ans == cor:
        # do stuff
    else:
        # do other stuff
```

Also, remove the `while` loop directly outside of this; it's not doing anything.